# Why can't I push to a GitLab repository?

Tags: git

we have a new GitLab server at our organization. I opened a new project and followed their Help-page to create an SSH pair. However I can't push an initial commit. This is how GitLab told me to do it:

```
cd existing_folder
git init
git remote add origin   
git@myorganization:Groupname/Projectname.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

All of those steps worked, except for the last one. When I try to push it says:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname myorganization: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I used `git remote -v` and I noticed that its output has `Myorganization` with an uppercase letter (somewhere in the middle; "myorganization" is just a placeholder). I then tried `git remote set-url origin` and entered the output from `git remote -v`. But trying to push still results in the above error. In the error message, `myorganization` remains lower case. I have no idea if case sensitivity could play a part here, it's just something I noticed.

Comment: It seems a DNS more than a GitLab issue. Does the ```host myorganization``` command resolve the IP of the machine?

Comment: do you have to use a proxy and if this is the case: did you set the proxy for git?

Comment: Yes, `host myorganization` as well as `host Myorganization` resolve the server IP.

Comment: Please [don't edit the answer into your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262807/2747593).  Instead, please post your solution as an answer.  ([It's okay to answer your own question.](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer))  After a 2-day waiting period, you can also [accept the answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a DNS issue of this specific machine. Instead of using username@gitlab.organization.local, username@gitlab worked.